# .slideToggle() on one paragraph instead of all others with same id

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I want it to work like this http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/JrhNz/6/ but instead of css classes i have ids.

Tried modifying my code with the ids instead of css classes and it doesn't work.

My code:

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>
            <p class=\"question\" id=\"question\">".$rand['nume']."</p>
            <p class=\"answer\" id=\"answer\">".$rand['rasp']."</p>
        </td>
      </tr>";

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#question").click(function(){
         var prev = $(this).prev("p#answer");
         $(this).siblings("p#answer").not(prev).slideUp("slow");
         prev.slideToggle("slow");
     });

     $("p#answer").click(function(){
         $(this).siblings("p#answer").slideUp("slow");
         $(this).slideToggle("slow");
     });
});​
```

Comment: "with same ID"? No element should have the same ID as another.

Comment: Don't treat the symptoms, treat the cause - IDs, by default, should not be repeated.

Comment: Yeah, ids must be unique. replace those ids and use a name attribute instead.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: `id`s _must_ be unique. Imagine if hundreds of people had the same government-issued ids, it would be a mess. Classes are different, it's like your gender, ethnicity, or religion, lots of people fall under the same category.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"p#answer"` with `"p.answer"` at all points in your code to target the class.

No element should have the same ID as another. If two or more elements on a page have the same ID, JavaScript will ALWAYS stop at the first one and ignore the rest.

Comment: It worked but now the paragraphs are sliding up when i click on the questions and they don't slide down after i click again on a question.